# Tomcat 7 log content of effective web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

This is probably obvious, but I can't find any details on it. After watching a video on tomcat 7, it was mentioned that it was possible to log the final web.xml after all the annotations in a web app had been processed. At this point, you could set metadata-complete to true and use the web.xml for production, thus improving performance. I've ran a quick test on an annotated servlet and I've not seen any generated web.xml in the logs (or anywhere else for that matter). I guess I'm missing something. Anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

I've found the answer, I seemed to miss this in the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> *logEffectiveWebXml* - Set to true if you want the effective web.xml
>   used for a web application to be logged (at INFO level) when the
>   application starts. The effective web.xml is the result of combining
>   the application's web.xml with any defaults configured by Tomcat and
>   any web-fragment.xml files and annotations discovered. If not
>   specified, the default value of false is used.

So, it's a case of defining a context and setting this attribute to true. I'll take it for a spin and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Ok, I had a go at this with <Context logEffectiveWebXml="true"> </Context> and it did indeed log the final web.xml. I don't quite get the rational behind  writing it to the log files. It looks pretty ugly. I'd have written the in memory structure to a web.xml..call it web-generated.xml or something. I guess there is a good reason why that is not a sensible move :)

Comment: Note - this should be added in META-INF/context.xml

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to see what is in that file? Or just know when it is started? If the latter then you can implement ServletContextListener and log whatever you need to see there. This is also where you can initialize and/or destroy an app configs.

Comment: I'm not sure of what hoops you need to jump to get this, I'm sure its very simple to achieve. There was a video on tomcat 7 features and the way he described this feature, you can effectively annotate a servlet and as soon as the tomcat engine has processed the annotations, somehow it logs the web.xml structure. You can then recycle that structure for the app and disable annotations to speed up performance. I just started playing with tomcat 7 and I'd like to know how to do this.

Comment: DariuszR, I get the feeling you don't need to register a listener to do this, I could very well be wrong about that.

Comment: Do you mean **lock** or **log**?